# Эффективный поиск подстрок(с большой базы данных) в рандомных строках

Tags: java, android, строки, поиск

Есть рандомная **стринга** которую вбил пользователь (вставил или получил с файла).
 Есть большая база данных (английских слов/ выражений) как лучше сделать поиски этих выражений/слов в **стринге**.
Мне приходит на мысль это создать работать по алфавиту с этой базой т.е. если это *extension* то только ***е*** . 
Возможно есть уже какие то библиотеки что бы не изобретать велосипед?

P.s. естественно суть в том что бы найти эти подстроки и их перевод максимально производительно

Comment: размер базы данный  и размер строки (хотя бы примерно) чтобы инструмент подобрать (совочек, лопату или 10 экскаваторов)

Comment: Строка может быть большая ) а искать надо в этой строке английские словосочетания/фразы (которые не переводятся прямо) и просто слова. Эти словосочетания, находятся в файле. Я пока этот файл не нашел но наверняка в нем будет достаточно строк информации

Comment: Я бы сказал что здесь подойдет любой поисковой движок, вроде solr. на выделенном под все это сервере. Если же хочется именно в одном приложении - преобразовывать файл в sqlite и пременять встроенный поиск.

Comment: Спасибо, я думаю это поможет)